# How to generate and bind a texture in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, textures, buffer, bind

I have inputted an image from file and stored it in a int array

```
private int[] dataBuffInt;
BufferedImage image;

image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/" + type + ".png"));
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();

this.dataBuffInt = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
```

I now want to take that array and pass it over to generate and bind my texture, however I am stuck as GLuint does not work for me.

```
GL11.glGenTextures(tex);
for (int i = 0; i < tex.length; i++) {
GL11.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[i]); }
```

This is where I am at I assume the for loop is completely wrong, I feel I need to get the colour from the int[] using Color c = new Color(dataBuffInt[100]) with c.getRed() etc but I am lost.

I hope someone understands my intentions, I am simply trying to read an image from a file and place it on screen.

There are no exceptions for reading the file in and the values are being successfully printed out for RGBA. I assume the Gen/Bind process has gone wrong.

Comment: Where are you sending the data buffer to the GPU? GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

Comment: What OpenGL bindings for Java are you using? Have you looked up how to use those bindings?

Comment: I pass the data buffer in as ant int [ ]  for my 2nd code phase as variable tex. I'm just not sure why it won't bind.